# combining dataframes and adding values on common date index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have many dataframes with one column (same name in all) whose indexes are date ranges - I want to merge/combine these dataframes into one, summing the values where any dates are common. below is a simplified example

```
range1 = pd.date_range('2021-10-01','2021-11-01')
range2 = pd.date_range('2021-11-01','2021-12-01')

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(range1),1), columns=['value'], index=range1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(range2),1), columns=['value'], index=range2)
```

here '2021-11-01' appears in both df1 and df2 with different values

I would like to obtain a single dataframe of 62 rows (32+31-1) where the 2021-11-01 date contains the sum of its values in df1 and df2

Comment: you could concat the dataframes using`df = pd.concat([df1,df2..], axis=0)` and then use the `df.groupby` , like `df.groupby('date`)['value'].sum()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `pd.concate()` on the two dataframes, then `df.reset_index()` to get a new regular-integer index, rename the date column, and then use `df.groupby().sum()`.

```py
df = pd.concat([df1,df2]) # this gives 63 rows by 1 column, where the column is the values and the dates are the index
df = df.reset_index() # moves the dates to a column, now called 'index', and makes a new integer index
df = df.rename(columns={'index':'Date'}) #renames the column
df.groupby('Date').sum()
```